# Shaking of my access form in maximized mode when I set list.recordset from sql server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an application that is created by MS access 2016 using forms, reports and module.

APP run with startup form and after 5 seconds opens main-form in maximized and without any access ribbon(I hide it).

I put several buttons in form header as a menu and on the detail a sub-form, a list-box and a search-box text. The data retrieves from SQL Server database and finally I set record-set of my sub-form and list-box from `rst`, for example set `me.lst.recordset=rst`

All things are good, but on setting record-set time to my objects my main-form shakes and move up and down

If my form is not maximized every thing is ok, but I would like to see main-form in maximized mode by default.

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with SQL Server or MS Access.

Comment: If you mean flickering is because you set Recordsource on the fly...shaking i can't really understand what might be.

Comment: Same Issue here... Did anyone find a solution for this behaviour?