# Access 2016: Assigning Combo-Box.Recordset via is raising resize event?

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I am assigning an adodb.recordset to a combo-box.recordset via

```
Set COMBOBOX.Recordset = adodb_rec
```

This raises the resize-event of my form. How can I prevent this?

It's the same issue mentioned in this post: [Shaking of my access form in maximized mode when I set list.recordset from sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155795/shaking-of-my-access-form-in-maximized-mode-when-i-set-list-recordset-from-sql-s)

Comment: I have never seen Recordset property used with combobox control. Usual approach is to set RowSource with SQL statement or query reference. Did you really name combobox as COMBOBOX?

Comment: Can't get it to work with ADO. Does work with DAO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate a ComboBox with a Recordset using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967399/how-to-populate-a-combobox-with-a-recordset-using-vba)

Comment: My question is not how to add data to a combobox, my question is, why does Access 2016 is flickering while adding a recordset. My question is related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155795/shaking-of-my-access-form-in-maximized-mode-when-i-set-list-recordset-from-sql-s

Comment: Don't know what you mean by 'resize-event'. I did not observe any shaking/flicker in my test.